# OracleDataAdapter hangs on Fill method in Windows XP

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, oracle11g

OracleDataAdapter hangs on Fill method in Windows XP.
While debugging In windows 7 works fine but VS2008 hangs on Windows XP.
The same applies to the release versions of the app. The sql query used has nothing to do, I have tested the function using simple queries and they all fail.

Here is a code snippet illustrating the initial code:

```
public static string DBSelectString(string ssql)
{
  try
  {
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand(ssql, Connection);
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Utils.Log(ex.Message);
    return string.Empty;
  }
}
```

Using OracleDataReader still hangs but I managed to find a workaround.

```
public static string DBSelectStringDR(string ssql)
{
  OracleDataReader reader = null;
  try
  {
    Connection.Open();
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(ssql, Connection);
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
      //reader.Read();
      //return reader.GetValue(0).ToString(); <-------- normally hangs here

      try
      {
        //workaround: 
        //force exception, since Read has not been executed
        string test = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
      }
      catch { }

      // then, everything works fine
      reader.Read();
      return reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
      return string.Empty;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Utils.Log(ex.Message);
    return string.Empty;
  }
  finally
  {
    if (reader != null) reader.Close();
    Connection.Close();
  }
}
```

Any ideas ?